# Name of a XIXth-century German scientist from the University of Berlin

Tags: mathematicians, biographical-details

In December 1892, the french mathematician Charles Hermite had a jubilee celebration.

He received a number of letters and telegrams. One of them is from the members of the University of Berlin, see the following picture:
[image: Letter from the University of Berlin]

I can identify all but one name:

[von Helmholtz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_von_Helmholtz) (physicist), [Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Weierstrass) (mathematician), [Kummer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Kummer) (mathematician), the missing one

[von Bezold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_von_Bezold) (physicist), [E. Dubois-Reymond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emil_du_Bois-Reymond) (physician), [Kundt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/August_Kundt) (physicist), [H.W. Vogel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Wilhelm_Vogel) (chemist), [Fuchs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazarus_Fuchs) (mathematician).

> Can you identify the missing one? (It seems that it is something like S. S...ers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Auwers.

All signatories (and Hermite) were members of the *Prussian Academy* : [1/1/1892](https://archive.org/stream/sitzungsberichte1892deut#page/n10), [1/1/1893](https://archive.org/stream/sitzungsberichte1893deut#page/n10).